# Passing contents of file to extglob command terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I have a list of files that I don't want to remove from a location, I have found that by using extglob I am able to keep a pre-defined list of files using:

```
rm -r !(one.txt|Folder)
```

This will remove everything except `one.txt` and the folder `Folder`, however the list of files that I want to keep isn't always the same.

Is there a way to pass a list of files/folders from a file e.g. `whitelist.txt` which won't be removed?

I have managed to reformat `whitelist.txt` to have the contents:

```
one.txt|two.txt|Folder
```

However I am unsure of how to pass that into the command

Just a note I am running OSX 10.11.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pathname expansion happens later than command substitution, you can combine the two:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !($(< whitelist.txt))
```

Comment: Just out of interest what does the $ do in this code?

Comment: @CampbellWray: `$(...)` is command substitution, it expands to the output of the enclosed command. See `man bash` for details.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this so much later, any thoughts on working with whitespace, I have tried putting the `$(...)` in quotation marks `"$(...)"` but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GLOBIGNORE` with a bit of trick:

```
GLOBIGNORE="$(tr '\n' ':' <file.txt)"
```

Assuming `file.txt` contains file names separated by newline. Of course don't forget to add `file.txt` to itself.

For `|` separated names:

```
GLOBIGNORE="$(tr '|' ':' <file.txt)"
```

Now you can do:

```
rm *
```

All files except those mentioned in `file.txt` will be removed.

Comment: What commands does this work with? if I wanted to use it with cp or mv would that work too?